# Does sizeof return the size of a malloc memory allocation?

Tags: c, malloc

What is the problem with the following memory allocation?

```
char *buffer;
buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
printf("buffer size: %ld\n", sizeof(buffer));
```

This prints 8 instead of 40 (which I expected). Something I missed in understanding  malloc or this is normal?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.  Also, `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: sizeof() is a **compile time** thing. How can it resolve a dynamically allocated (don't cast malloc return value) buffer?

Comment: @Adriano - not for VLAs, it isn't.

Comment: You're taking the size of a pointer, not of an array.

Comment: 1) http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html 2) pet peeve: `sizeof` is an operator, you only need parentheses if you want to apply it to a type name.

Comment: @CarlNorum right, I just let them out of this game because here it's not a vla

Comment: @CarlNorum casting the return value of malloc is not necessary, unless... you use a C++ compiler.

Comment: ...and at least 1000 others.

Comment: @gmorrow, this question is tagged [c].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sizeof(buffer)
```

returns the size of buffer, which is a pointer to char. Size of pointers to char on your machine is 8.

Comment: 8 bytes on 64-bit. 4 bytes on 32-bit.

Comment: @ZanLynx, right. In his case I deduced it's 8 without a great effort of imagination.

Answer (score 1):

The sizeof operator's result is entirely based on the type of the expression it operates on, not the identity or value. It can have no idea what size you passed to malloc unless you use a type that carries the size with it.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` is a pointer to `char`. When it will pass as argument to the `sizeof` operator, then `sizeof(buffer)` gives the size of pointer unlike the array names where it gives the size of the entire array in bytes. Always remember that *arrays are not pointers*.